# Subject-verb agreement when the subject is a dominant participle construction

Tags: classical-latin, syntax, participle, agreement

My **question** is whether constructions similar to the following English one, which is drawn from [Jespersen (1909-1949, vol. V: 138)](https://books.google.es/books?id=VYQiAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=%22Two%20old%20men%20dealing%20with%20such%20a%20young%20theme%22&source=bl&ots=0SwktG71Je&sig=ACfU3U2uscDN5Jgqh2i4buYjH59RsazX9g&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu7tmDq7jnAhUIuRoKHSYWBmYQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Two%20old%20men%20dealing%20with%20such%20a%20young%20theme%22&f=false), can exist in Latin, i.e., constructions where (i) the subject is formed by a plural noun plus an obligatory/"dominant" predicative participle but (ii) the verb is in singular form. Notice that it is not the two old men themselves that are funny, but the **fact** that they are dealing with an inappropriate theme. Hence singular agreement (*seem**s***) is justified.

> [Two old men dealing with such a young theme] seem**s** funny to me.

Next consider the two following examples of so-called "dominant" participle and gerundive constructions, taken from Sallust and Livy, respectively:

> (Dixit) se missum a M. Crasso qui Catilinae nuntiaret ne *eum Lentulus et Cethegus aliique ex coniuratione deprehensi terrerent*. (Sall. *Cat.* 48,4)

&

> Bello Graeci persequendi Publilio evenerunt. (Livy 8, 22, 9)

Although the subject is plural, I was wondering whether the verb could **also** be singular in these two examples (i.e., *terreret* and *evenit*). My intuition is that it couldn’t but perhaps I’m wrong (NB: as for the first Latin example above, it is not a plurality of individuals but the event/**fact** that these individuals were arrested what would frighten Catilina. Furthermore, note that *Lentulus* and *Cethegus* were accomplices/friends of Catilina: so it is clear that what could frighten Catilina was not them (as individuals), of course, but their arrest (i.e., a situation). As for the second example with a dominant gerundive, again it is not the Greeks but rather their having to be persecuted through a war (considered as as a future event to be accomplished, e.g., as a duty) what fell/"came" to the consul Publilius). Anyway, I would like to know whether examples like the English one above could also exist in Classical Latin.

---

Rethinking on this question, an invented Latin example similar to the attested English one above with the verb "seems" could be the following one:

> Cum legati occisi aliis pessimum, aliis pulcherrimum facinus **videretur**.

(cf. the attested example in Tacitus, who, as is well-known, uses many dominant participle constructions: *Cum occisus dictator Caesar aliis pessimum, aliis pulcherrimum facinus videretur* (Tac. *Ann.* 1.8). Note that, semantically speaking, the nominal predicate facinus ‘crime’ requires its subject to be a situation ('the murder of Caesar'), rather than an individual ('dictator Caesar')).

My intuition is that *viderentur* (3rd plural) would be the expected form in my invented example above but I don't know if *videretur* (3rd singular) would also be possible (perhaps, in this case, due to a possible attraction by *facinus*).

For a similar construction in Romance, cf. the Italian pseudorelative construction, drawn from [Casalicchio (2016)](https://www.academia.edu/34840592/The_Pseudo-relative_construction_in_Romance): *I bambini che giocano agli anziani mi {fanno/fa} ridere*; lit. 'The children that play at the elder {make/makes} me laugh'. According to this Italian linguist, both verbal forms *fanno* 'make.3pl' and *fa* 'make.3sg" are possible here.

Comment: FWIW, my intuition agrees with yours -- singular seems impossible here.

Comment: To talk about 'the fact that' some plural noun does something, and to have that fact be the subject of a singular verb, you'd have to, e.g., use a finite verb instead of a participle, and then use quod or ut at the beginning of the clause to render it a noun clause; or use an infinitive instead a participle, putting the subject into the accusative. In short, you can have either the participle or the singular verb, but not both.

Comment: In fact, it seems to me that, properly speaking, your English example with the singular verb doesn't involve a participle at all but a gerund. That is, it should really say 'Two old **men's** dealing with such a young theme....' However, colloquial English uses a participle instead of a gerund. In that case, the correct Latin equivalent would follow the 'more proper' English version and would likely use an accusative+infinitive instead of a participle.

Comment: The English example (without _'s_) is taken from Jespersen (1909-1949). I found it in  https://books.google.es/books?id=VYQiAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=%22Two+old+men+dealing+with+such+a+young+theme%22&source=bl&ots=0SsrlK82Eh&sig=QTRuleJL7LyeKgmCwc9NNmUtL5I&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFyqST6eHfAhWMzIUKHadTC64Q6AEwCHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Two%20old%20men%20dealing%20with%20such%20a%20young%20theme%22&f=false

Comment: I used an English example but the same phenomenon can be exemplified, perhaps even more intriguingly, with the so-called "pseudo-relative" construction in Italian. According to Jan Casalicchio, an Italian linguist (see his work below), in an It. example like _I bambini che giocano agli anziani mi {fanno/fa} ridere_ (lit. 'The children that play at the elder {make/makes} me laugh'), the verb can be plural (_fanno_) **or** singular (_fa_). Why is Latin different in the dominant participle constructions above? Cf. http://www.academia.edu/34840592/The_Pseudo-relative_construction_in_Romance

Comment: I have never seen such a *constructio ad sensum* as you suggest, but it can't be ruled out without examining literally every single relevant instance.

Comment: Stumbled upon interesting passage from *Carmina* (Venantius Fortunatus): *Quintiano demum sancto erudiente magistro \
pulchrius est auro corde probatus homo.*  . I believe it fits as why *pulchrius* and not *pulchrior*? can *pulchrius* be an adverb?

Comment: @d_e I'm afraid I don't see the relevance of your example from Late Latin here. What is your interpretation of it? In any case, please note that I'm interested in examples from Classical Latin (see my question above). Interestingly, the use of dominant participle constructions gradually declined in Late Latin but this is another issue (probably related to the decline of gerundive constructions and syntactically similar constructions in this period).

Comment: @Mitomino, oh, the way I parse this as such: *corde probatus homo* should be taken as a unit (I guessed that a dominant participle *probatus*). I would expect *pulchrior* as an adjective modifying *homo*, but here they use *pulchrius* in neutral - so I interpreted as violation of subject -"verb" agreement because of the dominant participle.

Comment: @d_e On the dominant participle reading, _homo probatus_ is interpreted as _hominis probatio_ (cf. _ab urbe condita_ with _ab urbis conditione_). However, it is not clear if this is the interpretation here. In any case, the existence of a neuter adjective (_pulchrius_) does not necessarily lead one to interpret the participle _probatus_ as a dominant one.  It could just be the case that _pulchrius_ is a neuter predicate ('something more beautiful') that applies to a non-neuter subject (cf. _Varium et mutabile sempre femina est_, where a neuter predicate applies to a feminine subject).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the subject here is more the participle than anything, which could indeed take a singular verb.

Comment: I agree with you in the first part of your answer ("It seems to me that the subject here is more the participle than anything"). Yes, that's why the construction at issue is often referred to in many textbooks of Latin syntax as "dominant participle construction". However, what you say in the second part of your answer ("which could indeed take a singular verb") is controversial, I think. One could expect it (given that the subject is a participial clause) but my intuition is that the main verb cannot be singular if the nominal within the dominant participle clause is plural.

Comment: I suppose you are right there...

Comment: @Mitomino: The first example: (he said) "he was sent by Marcus Crassus to assure Cataline that the apprehension of Lentulus, Cethegus & the others, from the conspiracy, ought not to alarm him....". This translation treats "arrest" as singular requiring singular verb "alarm" (terreret). Therefore the arrestees would have to be treated as one group (of individuals) requiring "deprehensum". This means changing the original version, how else could it work? The second ex., Graeci (plural) demands "evenerunt".  How to get around this--Graecia--Greece (singular);

Comment: @Mitomino: Continuing: but the country will not come out to Publius. Interesting theory; but, the strict demands of Latin grammar appear to undermine it.

Comment: Consider the (simplified) example: _occisus dictator Caesar pessimum facinus videbatur_. Crucially, if you eliminate the participle _occisus_, the sentence becomes ill-formed. That's why _occisus_ can be considered a "dominant" participle: i.e., it is obligatory. Now even if the "semantic subject" of _facinus_ is an event, i.e., a murder/killing, and not an individual (_dictator Caesar_), the agreement is always consistent with this individual and not with the event. So Latin seems to lack examples like the English one above taken from Jespersen. I'm wondering why...