# "M. Cato Censorius, quem tam e re publica fuit nasci quam Scipionem"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

In Seneca *Moral Letters* 87

> M. Cato Censorius, quem tam e re publica fuit nasci quam Scipionem, alter enim cum hostibus nostris bellum, alter cum moribus gessit, cantherio vehebatur et hippoperis quidem inpositis, ut secum utilia portaret.

I don't understand "*quem tam e re publica fuit nasci quam Scipionem*" both in grammar and sense. - grammatically it looks like *fuit* opens an object clause (acc + inf.) - but if that's so -- what does it mean? If not what is the subject in the *quem* clause?

Looking up Loeb translation wasn't helpful: "Marcus Cato the Censor, whose existence helped the state as much as did Scipio’s,—for while Scipio fought against our enemies, Cato fought against our bad morals ,—used to ride a donkey, and a donkey, at that, which carried saddle-bags containing the master’s necessaries.

Comment: Note that a syntactic variant of your interesting AcI construction could be a "dominant participle" construction: "M. Cato Censorius, _qui natus_ tam e re publica fuit quam Scipio..." (see this link [https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8839/subject-verb-agreement-when-the-subject-is-a-dominant-participle-construction]). E.g. cf. the typical ex. of a dominant participle construction "_occisus dictator_ facinus videbatur" with the AcI construction "_dictatorem occisum esse_ facinus videbatur" (cf. also the nominalization variant: "_Occisio dictatoris_ facinus videbatur").

Comment: BTW, a great latinist who was very supportive of using (in this case, syntactic) synonyms for a better learning of Latin was Rev. Reginald Foster [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reginald_Foster_(Latinist).

Comment: @Mitomino, interesting construction. Yeah, I guess Seneca had alternatives... I still find his choice somewhat odd when it could be expressed more directly like *qui juvat rem publicam*. I guess it put emphasis somewhere or simply because the idiomatic *e re publica*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see two main difficulties here.

### Special Meaning of *ex*

(1) First, Seneca is using a special sense of the preposition *e(x)*.

In the [Lewis & Short entry for *ex*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/ex) you can find the following meaning under heading III.G:

> Ex (e) re, ex usu or ex injuria, **to or for the advantage or injury of any one**

The phrase *e re publica* seems to be [particularly common](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23e+re+publica&first=1), particularly in Livy. See, for instance, this line from *Ab Urbe Condita* 6.23:

> dis bene iuuantibus ageret quod e re publica duceret

Translation:

> With the help of the gods he would do what would lead *to the benefit of the republic*.

### Subject is accusative + infinitive

(2) The other difficulty is that Seneca is using an accusative relative pronoun + infinitive as the *subject* of a relative clause. In this case, *quem nasci* is the subject of *fuit*.

---

Putting these two observations together, the parsing becomes clearer. Substituting *Catonem* for *quem*, the relative clause becomes:

> Catonem nasci tam e re publica fuit quam Scipionem [nasci].

Literal translation:

> Cato being born was as much for the benefit of the republic as Scipio [being born].

Comment: Hmm yes, this seems to be the only possible analysis. I don't remember seeing an a.c.i. as the subject of *sum* elsewhere: do you think it is common? I have seen an a.c.i. as the primary argument of an ablativus absolutus, though..

Comment: @Cerberus, where an infinitive clause is the subject, then the subject of the infinitive should be in the accusative case.  This example is very like *necesse est me abire* (*e re publica* functions like *necesse* here). I've encountered this several times (but never with *quem* as the subject of the infinitive).  Mitomino in a [question about this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16256/accusative-case-marking-of-subjects-in-infinitival-clauses)  says those "are not rare at all!" -- which says, well, they are quite rare lol :) at least rare enough to note they are not rare.

Comment: @d_e I agree: the syntax of the ex. is similar to that of _necesse est me abire_ in the sense that the acc. case of the subject of the infinitive is not assigned by the verb. As I noted in your link, this acc. case assignment pattern is _not_ rare (although it is not the prototypical one). The apparent "rarity" of the example can be related to the combination of this non-prototypical pattern with two additional facts: the subject of the infinitive clause is a relative pronoun and the predicate of the copular construction has an idiomatic interpretation (cf. supra: 'for the benefit of').

Comment: @d_e: Ah, right, when *e republica fuit* is seen as a kind of phrasal verb, then suddenly it looks far more 'normal', your comparison with *necesse est* is apt. Mitomino: Well said.